# JQuery JSON Undefined

Tags: jquery, html, json, mask, jsfiddle

I'm using the jquery iMask plugin found [here](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/#selflink_usage). Here is my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtQKh/1/)

When I run it
1) it doesn't work correctly. The input for phone is not masked like i set it up
2) the console displays the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Json is not defined fiddle.jshell.net:1
```

What is this error and how do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're able to mix jQuery and Mootools like that?

Comment: its weird that something is trying to reference `Json` as opposed to `JSON`.

Comment: @JezenThomas That's what the documentation for imask told me to do

Comment: Alright. Wasn't sure, just thought it looked suspect :)

Comment: @Ibsstr But it's not supposed to be the standard JSON object since it's calling `Json.evaluate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a `jQuery` plugin, it's a mootools plugin.

Use the `jQuery` port instead https://github.com/cwolves/jQuery-iMask

http://jsfiddle.net/GtQKh/9/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#phone').iMask({  
     type:'fixed',  
     mask:'(999) 999-9999',  
     stripMask: false
   });
});​
```

Comment: Your link isn't working, the one I posted is... You didn't include the jQuery plugin. I just pasted it from github into jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

To clear up confusion, iMask was originally created for MooTools and then someone also created a jQuery plugin. It seems you want to use jQuery event handlers so I'd recommend using the [jQuery iMask](https://github.com/cwolves/jQuery-iMask) plugin instead. Of course once you do this you will need to update your source code. Here is a basic [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YjTgD/) using jQuery iMask instead.

Please note that I used the GitHub source just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: okay do you know how to do an OR statement in regex? Like it can be this OR this: `(999) 999-9999 || 9 (999) 999-9999`

Comment: @Richard do not embed two questions into one, accept an answer for this question and create a new follow up question, linking it to this one.

Comment: @Richard The question is supposed to be useful to others in the future, when you ask too many things at once, it becomes too broad, we like nice succinct questions with specific answers