# How can I allow optional characters using iMask?

Tags: jquery, regex, input, mask

Here's my original post: [imask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608719/jquery-json-undefined#12608843)

I got that issue resolved but I'm wondering how to put multiple masks on an input. So for the phone input i want to put something like:

```
$('#phone').iMask({  
    type:'fixed',  
    mask:'(999) 999-9999 || 9 (999) 999-9999',  
    stripMask: false
});
```

But obviously that isn't working (or i wouldn't be posting). Anyone know how to do multiple conditions in a mask? Thanks

Comment: does iMask support multiple masks? The documentation doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in mask is not a regular expression, it's a custom mask format.

The following should work

```
 $('#phone').iMask({  
    type:'fixed',  
    mask:'9 (999) 999-9999',  
    stripMask: false
 });
```

If the user doesn't want to enter the first digit, they can just skip over it by using the arrow to skip over that number

http://jsfiddle.net/GtQKh/23/

Comment: You should replace `it's a custom mask format` with `it's a string representation`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Not sure why you think that is better. it's a string representation of what? of their own custom mask format.

Comment: it's a string representation of regexp; you can check their code to see that regexp is *exactly* what they use.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy But you can't enter regular expressions in that string. It's not a string representation of a regular expression. It's their own custom format for specifying a mask, almost looks like regular expressions, but you can only use a,x,9 and everything else is treated literally. It's like the `printf()` function, the string formatting in there may end up creating regular expressions, but it's not a string representation of a regular expression